# Running a Web Service application in VS2010

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have created a Web Service application in VS2010.  When I run the service, a web browser is supposed to appear and show my service.  But all I get is a directory listing of my source files.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Why would a directory listing of source files ever show up in a web service?

Comment: are you right clicking the right file?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project and open its properties.  Then go to the start options section and select the "Specific Page" and set it to the page that you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Since other applications are supposed to interface with the web service, it's not pertinent that it loads in your web browser.

I'm assuming what you're expecting is some type of page showing information on your service. In order to do that you just need to click the service file in the directory displayed in your browser. It probably has a .ASMX or .SVC extension. After that it should show some information about your service.